# Android - TextInputLayout Icon error not missing

Tags: android, icons, android-textinputlayout

I was missing the error icon in my activity log, in textInputLayout.
Not that time it has happened, but now only the error message, but not the icon appears.

In another activity where I have a form, if I appear, but do not appear on your site correctly, some appear double or even floating above others.

Does anyone know what happened? : -S

Thank you

Code example of one me input text:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="24dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/prompt_username"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Screenshot: [image]

Comment: can you add some screenshots to your post please to help the community answer :)

Comment: And the code too :)

Comment: add code and screenshot

Comment: you can do `setError` on the TextInputLayout with `setErrorEnabled`. it looks cleaner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is the main reason, but I've managed to solve.

Apparently the version: compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0' has this problem. Can anyone confirm?

I returned to the compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.0' and has been fixed.

Comment: Yes i can confirm. Apparently there are a lot of bugs in the android design libraries. Changing your library version does remove a lot of problems